# What is the meaning of each element of feColorMatrix?

Tags: html, matrix, svg-filters

What is the meaning of each of feColorMatrix values?

I have got a black svg shape, it must be masked with #26bf8c color. I am trying to find the meaning of that matrix to convert my HEX to it?

```
<svg width='20px' height='10px' preserveAspectRatio='none meet'>
    <image filter='url(#colorMatrixFilter1)' width='20px' height='10px' xlink:href='../img.svg' />
    <defs>
        <filter id='colorMatrixFilter1'>
            <feColorMatrix type='matrix'
                    values='1 0 0 0 0
                            1 0 0 1 0
                            1 0 0 0 0
                            0 1 0 1 0
                    '/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I thought I can write down rgb values as their binary representation but it seems that matrix works a different way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To recolor an element to a specific color, you have to do this.

- Specify "color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
- Convert your hex values to the unit scale (0 - 1).
- Put the R/G/B values in the fifth column, first three rows of your matrix.

Your specific matrix would be:

```
        <filter id='colorMatrixFilter1' color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feColorMatrix type='matrix'
                values='0 0 0 0 0.149
                        0 0 0 0 0.749
                        0 0 0 0 0.548
                        0 0 0 1 0'/>
    </filter>
```

All of the values in the first four columns are multipliers. They take the value of each color channel for every pixel, multiply it by the value of that matrix cell, and add it to another color channel. The fifth column is an offset - it adds a fixed value to each color channel.

Cell 1,1 of the matrix is a red -> red multiplier

Cell 2,1 of the matrix is a green -> red multiplier (in column, row notation)

Cell 1,2 of the matrix is a red -> green multiplier (in column, row notation)
etc..

To see what each cell does - you can play with a live Color Matrix here:
https://beta.observablehq.com/@gitmullany/filter-effects-using-svg-color-matrices

Comment: This matrix just sets the whole image to be the same color regardless of what color each pixel was. I think @CodeGust wanted to only change the black portions of the image to the new color, since they used the word "mask".

Comment: @bradn - I think the op was using "mask" just to mean recolor - which is probably why he accepted the answer.